# How to use the greater-than character as a shortcut trigger in AutoHotkey?

Tags: special-characters, autohotkey

The question is quite straight forward, I want pressing the <kbd>></kbd> character to send <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Something like

```
>::Send, {Tab}
```

but that doesn't seem to work, probably because the '>' is used to denote right-(ctrl|alt|shift). How do I escape it? Tried `{>}` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does work:

Code before or after your hotkey might be affecting how it works.

Try putting your code at the top of the script.

If that doesn't work, RIGHT CLICK the autohotkey icon on your taskbar, then click "Edit This Script". Save and replace the script with just:

```
>::Send, {Tab}
```

RIGHT CLICK the autohotkey icon on your taskbar again, then click "Reload This Script". Now test <kbd>></kbd> again.

Comment: You're right, it works. Something in my script intervenes.

Comment: I was creating a new file and including it in the main script, but apparently "Reload This Script" doesn't run the `#Include` commands. Exiting and re-starting the script solved it.

Comment: `Reload this script` does parse `#includes`.  The contents of the #includes can make a difference though